# How do i implement facebook like functionality?

Tags: c#, facebook

I've seen many websites which give facebook icon and if we click it automatically our friends know that we have liked that item. How can we implement that functionality? I am using C# Asp.Net

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you *can* do it with C#, your life will be A LOT easier if you do it with JavaScript in a ASP.NET application.  To get started look at the [Facebook Javascript SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)

If you absolutely insist on doing this through C# I would recommend using the [C# Facebook sdk](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/).

Comment: You don't even need JavaScript (though it allows a few more features).  There is also a IFRAME option.

Answer (score 3):

Simply emit an Like iframe in your ASP.Net page

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?
href=<% =Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.ToString()).ToString() %>
&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like
&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" 
allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

notice `<% =Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.ToString()).ToString() %>`
this makes you like plugin refer any page you are in your website.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Like](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) social plugin.

Comment: please give some details then a link.